# How to submit a form on Mechanize then submit to the next form that loads

Tags: python-3.x, mechanize-python

Sorry if the title is poor. This code is copied, so I don't know what the first few lines do.

The site I want to scrape first asks for the email, which after submission asks for the password. When I inspect element, the password form is loaded only after the email is entered.

```
cj = http.cookiejar.CookieJar() #not sure what this does
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)
br.open("http://stream.bayyinah.tv")

br.select_form(nr=0)
br.form['email'] = 'myemail'
br.submit() #only way to get the password form to load?
br.select_form()
br.form['password'] = 'mypassword'
br.submit()
```

The last three lines are incorrect for sure.